# Support Vector Machine / K-nearest-neighbor code samples

Tags: java, ruby, artificial-intelligence, svm, knn

I am trying to code up either a SVM or a KNN program to classify text documents. I grasp the concepts of both, but I would love to see some nice code examples that specifically demonstrate how to represent the text/words as vectors. Any one know of good tutorials/articles/lectures/anything with code examples? Even code that I could step through myself would be nice. I'm best at ruby and java, although python, javascript, c++ I can understand. I'll take examples in any language though really.

Comment: Try using libsvm, or taking a look at its source code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your SVM library input file format. For instance, the libsvm file format requires that each feature is encoded as an integer, and furthermore, that the feature indices are in ascending order.

More info here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#/Q3:_Data_preparation